# ASP.Net Core telerik grid custom

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, telerik

Currently I'm using [ASP.Net Core Telerik grid](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/paging)

I activated the PageSizes option as:

```
.Pageable(pager => pager
        .PageSizes(new [] { 10 ,25 ,50 })
        )
```

That is working but I want to add label at the start of dropdown an modify the default "items per page" label to be as:

```
show [dropdown] entries
```

[image]

Currently I use onDataBound jQuery function to change some style

I try to access the "items per page label" and I can remove it as:

```
 function onDataBound(e) {
            const grid = this;
            ...
     $('.k-pager-sizes')
        .contents()
        .filter(function () {
            return this.nodeType === 3;
        }).remove();
            });
        }
```

But I have no idea how to change it and how to add the new label at the beginning. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Finally I found the way to change "items per page label" as :

```
.Pageable(pager => pager
        .PageSizes(new [] { 10 ,25 ,50 })
        .Messages(m =>
        {
            m.ItemsPerPage("entries");
        })
        )
```

but now I need to know how to add label "show" at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not an API method to set the text before the dropdown. You can modify the pager after page load with some javascript to inject text. Here's an example in vanilla javascript

```js
// assums pager with id "pager", then gets container for iterms-per-page dropdown, selecting the first dom node.
// Will want to change this to iterate if there is more than one pager on the page that needs to change
var target = document.getElementById('pager').getElementsByClassName('k-pager-sizes')[0].childNodes[0];

// Create a new <span> element
var content = document.createElement('span');
// Add a margin on the right.
content.style.marginRight   = "8px";
// Set text content of span element.
content.innerHTML = 'Show';

// Insert the new <span> element before the items-per-page dropdown
target.parentNode.insertBefore(content, target);
```

complete example: https://dojo.telerik.com/oNIFoKEb

Comment: I tried to use outside and inside my onDataBound method but console throwing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getElementsByClassName')`

Comment: nvm, I just changed the id for mine..., it appears! but it is showing 3 times:  Show Show Show, to solve this I just separate into a new function, now it works!